# Event if some node in tree of nodes gets focus

Tags: java, javafx

Let's suppose we have a tree of nodes, something like:

```
          VBox
           |
         /   \
      Pane SplitPane 
     /              \
    HBox             Pane
  /     \             |
Button   Button   TextField
```

What is the optimal way (without setting listener on every node) to get event when any node of this tree gets focus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use for example the [`focusOwnerProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html#focusOwnerProperty) of the `Scene`:

> The scene's current focus owner node.

```
scene.focusOwnerProperty().addListener((obs, oldval, newval) ->
        System.out.println(checkFocus(vbox)));
```

where `checkFocus` checks recursively the [`focusedProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#focusedProperty) of the nodes originated from the `VBox`:

```
private boolean checkFocus(Parent p) {
    if (!p.isFocused()) {
        for (Node node :p.getChildrenUnmodifiable()) {
            if (node instanceof Parent && checkFocus((Parent) node))
                return true;
            else if (node.isFocused())
                return true;
        }
    } else 
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. If I have a TabPane with multiple tabs and every tab has its own node tree. How do you think, should I create new scene on every Tab to use such solution?

Comment: You cannot add a `Scene` to a `TabPane` (or anywhere to the scene-graph) as the `Scene` is the root of the scene-graph. You can use in approach of course inside the content of your tab(b). You can call the same method similar times on different target `Parent`s.

Comment: Thank you. Do I understand right - listener added via `scene.focusOwnerProperty().addListener()` will get event when focus changes anywhere inside tree?

Comment: Yes, as that property stores the !single! focused `Node` in the scene-graph and gets notified if this focused node has been changed.